# Failed to import any qt binding - Spyder on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pyqt, spyder

I'm trying to animate a trajectory of an object in 2D using python.
The problem is, when i try to do so I get this famous error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Pierre\OneDrive\Documents\Etudes\Master\M2\Stage\tests\sympy and gekko.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2336, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 276, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 277, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))

  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 16, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui

  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 177, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Failed to import any qt binding")

ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding
```

I tried every solution I found (installing PyQt5 and importing it, reinstalling matplotlib, updating pip) and nothing works. I still get the same error every time.

I'm on windows 10 and I installed python (3.9.2) using chocolatey. I'm coding with spyder 4.2.2

I've seen someone speaking about how updating his GPU driver helped but mine is up to date and still nothing (Radeon RX580).

Does anybody have a clue on what could be the issue ?

Comment: did you install `Qt` (framework created in C/C++ ) before `PyQt` (module created in Python) ?

Comment: @furas I tried installing it but it seems quite complicated. I'm not used to these things. I tried installing Qt creator and the dependencies and Pyside2. Now "import PyQt5" isn't working and I still don't have any animation. I can pick Qt5 in Spyder's options though

Comment: @furas Ok now it works I don't know why. I will edit the message. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Installing Pyside2 did the trick. No need to for the `import PyQt5` if you have the option picked in the preferences of Spyder